# grails 2.3.3 command validation error messages

Tags: validation, grails

We recently upgraded from 2.2.3 to 2.3.3, and now the error messages for the failing validation of commands are not being picked up from messages.properties.

As stated here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html I updated the error codes to not have .error at the end.

This is my command:

```
@Validateable
class GroupCommand {
  String name


  static constraints = {
    name blank: false, unique: true
  }
```

This is the entry in grails-app/i18n/messages.properties :

```
groupCommand.name.blank=Please enter a name for that group
```

And this is the error message I get when validation fails:

`Property [name] of class [class au.edu.rmit.its.iim.googlegrey.GroupCommand] cannot be null`

I tried adding full package description, adding .error, well all combinations really and this message is not picked up by validation.

I can get them using the message tag, but the validation system does not find them.

Has anyone foud a workaround for this, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the default message provided for `blank` constraint in `messages.properties`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new data binder in 2.3 converts blanks to null - see http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew23

You can configure this:

```
grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull = false
```

See http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0/guide/single.html#dataBinding for more details

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for that, I was wondering why it was null instead of blank, but didn't connect the dots.